# Laravel 5.5 подключить свой класс в контроллере

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Есть файл "MyClasses.php" в папке "App":

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Model1 extends Model {}
class Model2 extends Model {}
```

Как его подключить в контроллере с помощью use?

Answer (score 1):

Данный подход является плохим тоном в разработке. Laravel использует `composer` для автозагрузки классов и следует стандартам psr-4.

Касательно текущего вопроса - **КАЖДЫЙ КЛАСС В ОТДЕЛЬНОМ ФАЙЛЕ!!! НАЗВАНИЕ ФАЙЛА = ИМЯ КЛАССА**

Рекомендуется следовать стандартам кодинга, чтобы в твоем коде могли быстро разбираться другие разработчики, а также это необходимо, чтобы автозагрузчик классов корректно работал.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Интересно почему нельзя все модели хранить в одном файле как в Django в файле "models"?

Comment: потому что не будет работать автоматический автолоадинг классов